# What is the name of the View that shows options like the Camera Roll?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios5

I want to create a button that show options like the Send option of the Camera Roll, but I don't know what kind of view is this to add the button, can anybody help me?

Comment: UIBarButtonItem for the button or UIPopoverController for the list of options that come off it.

Comment: Do you mean the button on the right side of the navigation bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for an **UIBarButtonItem** created with *UIBarButtonSystemItemAction*.

```
UIBarButtonItem * baritem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction systemItem target: some_view action:@selector(some_method:)];
```

[Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html) - scroll to near bottom to see constants for possible predefined buttons with examples.

Comment: http://vtcdn.com/sites/default/files/imagecache/med/images/2009/9/10/img-1252572135-11.png This is the correct URL

Comment: This is what I need, sorry if I didn't explain well

Comment: You mean the view that pops up from the bottom? If so, it's an **UIActionSheet**.

Comment: That was Peter! Thanks a lot for your help!